# Error al momento de generar backup de equipo en red c#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Al momento de usar mi método backup , me encuentro con un error que a continuación detallo con una imagen.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi metodo generar_backup realiza un backup de mi bd en teoría desde cualquier pc que se encuentre conectado a la red y con conexión a la bd, lo raro es que sale este error pero en otros formularios accedo y guardo información sin problema.

Adjunto mi método el cual solo funciona en la maquina que se encuentra instalado el sql server con la bd respectiva, en otras maquinas de red al momento de realizar sale el error que muestro arriba.

```
 public void Generar_Backup()
    {
        try
        {
            Crear_Carpeta_Backup();
            Borrar_Carpeta_Backup(@"d:\Backup", deleteThis: false);
            var backup = new Backup();
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Integrated Security=SSPI; Data Source=SISTEMAS-PC");
            var sc = new ServerConnection(con);
            Server server = new Server(sc);
            backup.Action = BackupActionType.Database;
            backup.Database = "DIENTES_SANOS";
            backup.Devices.AddDevice(@"d:\Backup\Backups.bak", DeviceType.File);
            backup.BackupSetName = "DIENTESSANOSDB";
            backup.Initialize = false;
            backup.PercentComplete += CompletionStatusInPercent;
            backup.Complete += Backup_Completed;
            backup.SqlBackup(server);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("ERROR:" + ex.Message, "ERROR!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
```

De antemano les agradezco su ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Deberías revisar si tienes acceso a la base de datos desde otro equipo. También veo que te falta agregarle el usuario y pass para la conexión:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Integrated Security=SSPI; Data Source=SISTEMAS-PC");
```

Ya que si es el backup desde otro equipo debes de autenticarte.